# NSUser default with app group not working in IOS 10 & above

Tags: objective-c, ios-app-group

We are successfully integrated two application with `app` group `enablement`.
However when trying to retrieve the date from the `Userdefault` in `IOS` version 10 and above we are getting the following error :

Failed to read values in `CFPrefsPlistSource<0x170107c50> (Domain:"Group name", User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null)): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser` with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from `cfprefsd`

We are using the following code to retrieve the data :

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] initWithSuiteName:groupname];    
[shared synchronize];
NSString *jsonString = [shared stringForKey:@"key"];
```

But we tried in ios version 9, we are successfully retrieving the data.

Please help.

Comment: what is the value of `groupname`?

Comment: The value is group.xxx.xxx.xxx in both the application.

Comment: yeah.......... so, let me rephrase that: **could it be `nil`?**

Comment: `alloc` then `init`, what's wrong with `init` following `standardUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
NSString *suiteName = @"your group bundle id";
_userDefalut = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:suiteName];
```

Or you can go to the group sandbox path check more details.

```
NSString *suiteName = @"your group bundle id";
NSString *groupPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:suiteName]
```